# Are finishing bits sold as such?

Tags: powertools, routers

One of the answers for [another question of mine](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/15834/887) recommended using a finishing bit in my router to leave about 1/16" protrusion remaining to be sanded. When I search for "finishing bit" though I can't seem to find anything labeled like that for sale. Is there another term I could look for, or does "finishing bit" just refer to a particular configuration of another bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure.  We get our flush bits sharpened which takes down the blades which doesn't cut flush anymore.

What you can do is change the bearing to a different diameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of types of router bits.  You are probably looking for a flush cutting or chamfer bit.  If you look at a site like Rockler woodworking  or just google "types of router bits" you will find many sites with large selections. Even the box stores like Lowes and HD have a decent selection of basic bits.